# Does com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(long size) allows max records up to record-count of size?

Tags: guava

Does com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(long size1)  allows max records up to record-count of size1 ?

In debugging we found that it validates totalWeight > maxSegmentWeight in LocalCache.evictEntries method... and result in lesser number of records than expected(i.e. size1)...    How to achieve size1 ?

Comment: You probably want `Suppliers.memoize` for a single item cache.

Comment: Hi Ben,  I couldn't understand your comment above.  Can you share some more detail or code example that will be helpful?    Is it similar behavior on maximum-sizing in Caffeine?

Comment: often when a one item cache is used it also uses a surrogate key. Instead of a k/v cache, a supplier provides a better abstraction. Here’s a [tutorial](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/lazy-loading-and-caching-objects-in-java-with-guava-s-suppliers-memoize).

Comment: I think the variable name, size1, made me think you might be asking for a one element cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store precisely `size` values, then in general you must also configure your cache with `concurrencyLevel(1)`.

Comment: What is the side effect of having ConcurrencyLevel as 1?

Comment: The effect is that the cache is not divided into segments whose size is managed independently (it is divided into only one segment).

Comment: Is default concurrencyLevel 4?    Would that mean that after making "ConcurrencyLevel as 1"  throughput will be ~1/4 ? (i.e. will cause performance impact)

Comment: That depends on whether you're using multiple threads to access the cache.

Comment: Considering we have single thread accessing the cache,  can it be safely assumed that keeping concurrencyLevel as 1 will cause throughput to be ~1/4 of what is with default concurrencyLevel  i.e. 4 ?

Comment: If you have a single thread accessing the cache, throughput will not change at all.  The concurrency level is an estimate of how many threads can _use_ the cache without contention, not how many threads the cache uses.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.   So considering how many threads accessing the cache,   yes there can be multiple concurrent threads accessing the cache like 10 concurrent threads ..     so  in that scenario, keeping concurrencyLevel as 1 will cause throughput to be ~1/4 ... correct?

Comment: That's correct.  If you want to get up to the _exact_ size you want and never evict entries until you hit that size, you must sacrifice throughput and concurrency.